# read forwarded emails header and body in php

Tags: php, email, email-bounces

In my mail box, I got bounced emails which are forwarded from other server.

When I check show source from mail application, it gives me all custom headers which I want.
So I want to **read original source** to get all headers.

I checked out imap_fetchheader, imap_body etc but it did'nt worked out for me.

Is there a way to get text of show original source of email using code?

Comment: what problem you are getting with imap_fetchheader.

Comment: Hi Rohitashv, imap_fetchheader is not getting all headers or original message header, this get the current email header only not get headers of forwarded original message.